# OpenGL Mouse Input

Tags: java, opengl, input, mouse, lwjgl

I have this mouse function in my OpenGL program:

```
public void mouseInput(){
    int mouseX = Mouse.getX();
    int mouseY = 600 - Mouse.getY();
    int mouseDX = 0, mouseDY = 0;
    int lastX = 0, lastY = 0;

    mouseDX = mouseX - lastX;
    mouseDY = mouseY - lastY;

    lastX = mouseX;
    lastY = mouseY;

    xrot += (float) mouseDX;
    yrot += (float) mouseDY;

}
```

I rotate the "camera" using this code:

```
glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(yrot, 0.f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

And I call the mouseInput() function in the `!DisplayIsClosedRequested` loop. Currently this causes my game to freak out and my camera rotates all over the place even without me touching the mouse. The cubes I have rendered out also move around the screen randomely. I am using LWJGL, so I cant use any glut functions like `glutPassiveMotionFunc()`. Can anyone offer help? Basically in summary, my camera is very jerky and rotates the camera in random patterns very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the camera is rotating even when you are not touching the mouse, you are probably applying the rotation over and over again. You could reset the camera view matrix first (`glLoadIdentity()` in OpenGL 2 fixed-functionality), every frame, and *then* apply the rotation. That way you will only rotate from a fixed reference point every frame, instead of the last reference point which was the result of a rotation from a previous frame.